# Read txt document, each read two hexadecimal number, to achieve automatic reading the next line, and write data into the list

Tags: python

I have a multi-line txt document with hexadecimal Numbers.I want to read one byte at a time (two hexadecimal digits), convert it to a decimal digit, and save it to the list.I want the first row read to complete, then the second row to be read automatically, one byte at a time, until the document is finished.

For now, I can read one row correctly, one byte at a time (two digits), and convert one byte to decimal in the list.But after the first row is read, an error occurs when the second row is read.For example, The second row of data is: 15003FD51FFB reads 1,50,03, FD, 51, FF, which is wrong.The correct values should be 15,00, 3f,D5,1F,FB, and converted to decimal digits.

```
def main():
    f = open('ceshi.txt','r')
    list_1 = []
    list_2 = []
    while True:
        c1 = f.read(2)
        if not c1:
            break
        else:
            ip_hex = int(c1,16)
            list_1.append(ip_hex)        
    print(list_1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My txt document content is:

```
150032F31D
15003FD51F
15003EF31F
```

The output I want is:

```
21, 0, 50, 243, 29，21, 0, 63, 213, 31，21, 0, 62, 243, 31
```

The first line：`21, 0, 50, 243, 29`

The second line：`21, 0, 63, 213, 31`

The current program output error program is:

```
21, 0, 50, 243, 29, 1, 80, 3, 253, 81, 15, 21, 0, 62, 243, 31
```

When reading the second line, a byte (two digits) should be read, but the program gives error reading 1,50,03, FD, 51, F，the correct reading is:15，00,3F,D5,1F.

When the third row is read, the data read is correct and one byte is read at a time: 15,00,3e,F3,1F.

Comment: It seems you are reading the new line character here `c1 = f.read(2)` once you are at the end of a line. You'll need to check for and discard the bytes that are newline.  I found some useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896278/ignore-newline-character-in-binary-file-with-python

Comment: You will find it much easier to read the file line by line (`for line in f:`) and split each line into a list of groups of two hex digits (`[line[c:c+2] for c in range(0,len(line.strip()),2)]` and convert the elements of the list.